# Galera Mysql Cluster XA transactions alternative

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb, percona, galera

On Galera Mysql Cluster (either Percona or MariaDB) limitation refers that XA transactions are not supported, cause of cluster nature, which is perfectly understand. My question: (i am not a developer so please show some mercy on me) is there any mechanism that replies an OK if the statement has been committed to majority of nodes - something like MongoDB write concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera replication is synchronous and when a write query gets back to you, the data is on every node in the cluster.  If for any reason a node cannot apply the transaction, it will kill itself to maintain the integrity of data throughout the cluster.

Comment: it will kill itself means it will shutdown itself?

Comment: Yes, it will gracefully shut itself down.